# What should I do with units after I've got the TMR?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I have a number of units which I don't really use, but have got the Trust Master Reward (TMR) already. I've since got more duplicates of the unit.

It makes sense to me to start working on a new TMR for the new unit, to use the duplicates.

However, what should I do with the unit with 100% TMR which I don't use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're still good for experience, with other units, or depending on the Reward, they can be worth trying to obtain again.

The TMR is a bonus for your units - that is rare and can make those particular units more powerful when unlocked. They can be traits, spells, or items, so it would make sense to make them harder to obtain.

However once they're unlocked, you can, especially in the case of items, work toward unlocking them a second time around. Otherwise, use them to level up your other units, who may already have their TMR unlocked.